# Equivelent to D-Link Virtual Server for Linksys

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I used to use a D-LINK DIR-825 router.  It had a feature called "Virtual Server List" where I would forward specific public ports to specific private IPs and ports (see below image).  I know have a Linksys AC-1750 router.  How do I perform this same functionality?

[image: Virtual Server List]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

EDIT.  Added image of D-Link Port Forwarding

[image: D-Link Port Forwarding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as "Port forwarding". From [the manual](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/1224698268757/EA6700_combo_PDF_En-FrCA.pdf), I would:

- Log into Linksys Smart Wi-Fi
- Under Router Settings, click Security
- Click the Apps and Gaming tab Click Single Port Forwarding. The
  Single Port Forwarding screen opens
- Click Add a new Single Port Forwarding
- In the Application name field, enter a descriptive name.
- In the External Port field, type the external port number (not always
  required).
- In the Internal Port field, type the internal port number (not always  required).
- In the Protocol drop-down list, select TCP, UDP, or Both (default).
- In the Device IP# field, enter the last three digits of the IP address you  have reserved for the computer you want to forward Internet traffic to. The rest of the IP address has   already been completed for you.
- Select Enabled, then click Save. If you don’t want to use port forwarding  but want to keep the  information in the table, unselect the checkbox

Comment: Thanks Sahmeepee.  I will give it a try.  Kind of cryptic that you need to go through "Apps and Gaming tab", but oh well.

Comment: In addition to D-Link's "virtual server", D-Link also has "port forwarding".  What is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong sir! Virtual server is NOT the same as port forwarding!!!!

Port Forwarding creates a 1:1 relationship between your public IP address and a single private IP address.  For example:

Forward Port 3389 (Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol RDP) to 192.168.0.198 means:

your.public.ip.address:3389 gets forwarded to 192.168.0.198:3389

But let's assume you have more than one system behind your router you want to access RDP.  If you're simply forwarding 3389 to .198, given the 1:1 nature of port forwarding, then you are limited to only one system you can access.  In comes virtual server.

Virtual server creates 1:many relationship between your public IP address and multiple private addresses.  It can be used in conjunction with Port Forwarding.  Assuming you are still using the port forwarding rule above, and you want to add two more RDP ports forwarded you can do this:

Forward Port 64001 to 192.168.0.197:3389 
Forward Port 64002 to 192.168.0.196:3389

You could do the same with FTP servers, Web servers, etc.

Comment: It's still called port forwarding even when you direct it to a different port.

Comment: Technically speaking, what you describe is a [virtual switch](https://www.google.com/#q=virtual%20switch), not a virtual server.  You are right you would forward the port to the virtual switch, and all traffic on the switch, would be sent to all devices connected to it.